# UcanaccessSQLException: Unsupported newer version: 32

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

```
import java.sql.*;  

class Test{  

    public static void main(String ar[]) {  
        try {  
            //String url="jdbc:odbc:logingdsn";  
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");  
            Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\aCER\\Desktop\\login.laccdb");  
            Statement st=c.createStatement();  
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from logintable");  
            while(rs.next()){  
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));  
            }  

        } catch (Exception ee) { 
            System.out.println(ee);
        }  

    }
}
```

I'm using UCanAccess jar file for ms access db connectivity in 
   jdk1.8/jre/lib/ext ...

I have included all required jar files but I'm still getting this exception

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.x.x Unsupported newer version: 32

and its not loading driver class. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The `.laccdb` file does not contain the database objects (tables, views, etc.). It is a lock file that the Access Database Engine uses to manage connections to the main database file, which is the `.accdb` file.

So, your connection URL should point to the `.accdb` file, not the `.laccdb` file.