# Connect java to Microsoft Access Database

Tags: java, maven, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I've been trying to connect to a microsoft access 2007 database using the 'ucanaccess' library for a few hours.

But it is impossible for me since I always get the error 'Unsupported newer version: 32' when connecting. I have tried all released versions of 'ucanaccess' using maven and none worked for me.

Error stacktrace:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::5.0.1 Unsupported newer version: 32
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:231)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
at morales.david.server.utils.AccessConnection.open(AccessConnection.java:26)
at morales.david.server.managers.ImportManager.importDatabase(ImportManager.java:42)
at morales.david.server.clients.ClientProtocol.receiveFile(ClientProtocol.java:169)
at morales.david.server.clients.ClientProtocol.parseInput(ClientProtocol.java:40)
at morales.david.server.clients.ClientThread.run(ClientThread.java:67)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unsupported newer version: 32
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.JetFormat.getFormat(JetFormat.java:309)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.<init>(DatabaseImpl.java:538)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.open(DatabaseImpl.java:415)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:267)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DefaultJackcessOpener.open(DefaultJackcessOpener.java:37)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReference.<init>(DBReference.java:171)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReferenceSingleton.loadReference(DBReferenceSingleton.java:51)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:91)
... 7 more
```

Version I'm using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ucanaccess</groupId>
    <artifactId>ucanaccess</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is the code I use to open de connection:

```
public void open() {
    try {

        String path = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\david\\Desktop\\dam.accdb";

        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(path);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Would someone know how to fix it?

Comment: can we see the code where you try to open the file?
reading another similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630552/ucanaccesssqlexception-unsupported-newer-version-32 , the user tried to open the laccdb and not the accdb file.

Comment: @LuciferSam Hi, I updated the question with the code. 
I readed all questions of this problem, but anyone helps

Comment: Side note: _It is urgent_ - This is a community of volunteers. I am sure someone will be able to help you with a great answer, but it is generally not necessary (or helpful) to tell us an issue is urgent.

Comment: An observation: URLs such as the JDBC URL you use for `path` generally need to use forward slashes (`/`). You can replace your double-backslashes (`\\\`) with single forward slashes. I do not know if this will resolve your problem, though.

Comment: check the Jackaccess library version installed by Maven, and if it's not the latest version try to update it. (reading around SO someone solved updating it)

Comment: @andrewjames Yeah, I tried it, but gives the same error. Thanks anyway for the recomendation.

Comment: @LuciferSam Updated all dependencies to the lastest versions, but nothing. Gives the same error

Comment: Is UcanAccess a must? jOOQ tends to keep more abreast of database versions.

Comment: @kolossus No, I just need a connector library like mysql one, but for MS Access.
And I only found 'ucanaccess' for java +8

Comment: Definitely checkout jooq. It [supports MS Access](https://www.jooq.org/download/) but not for free. But it *actually* supports it in that Lukas keeps up to date with different databases and their quirks, as well as provides actual customer support for the commercial license.

Comment: @kolossus I need a free solution, sorry

Comment: yeah 800$ can be a big sum of money, especially if you need to do this once.
You could write a quick program written in C# using OleDB driver for MS Access using "Access Database Engine" but it works only under Windows, and export the data in CSV or JSON or XML and then import somewhere else using Java.
Just install the right version of ADE for 32 or 64 bits depending if you compile C# program for 32 or 64 bits.
PS: You can install only one version of ADE 2016 : or 32 or 64 bits, not both.